# Pass environment variable to python module from gcloud ai custom-jobs create CLI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

[According to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create), it is possible [to pass environment variables to python module](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/CustomJobSpec#pythonpackagespec) using a config file with the `--config` argument of `gcloud ai custom-jobs create`.

However I'd prefer not to use a config file and use only the CLI. Is it possible to use only the CLI to pass environment variables to the packaged python code?

I am adding a base command line that I would like to expand so that it takes also environment variables to pass to the job.

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
  --region=europe-west9 \
  --display-name=try_vai \
  --python-package-uris=gs://data-analyses/r_d/try_vertex_ai/dist/try_vertex_ai-0.1.tar.gz \
  --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=e2-standard-4,replica-count=1,executor-image-uri=europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/scikit-learn-cpu.0-23:latest,python-module=src.try_vertex_ai
```

Comment: Yes, you can add your environment variable in the container spec section.

Comment: okay, can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

I took the sample of the [gcloud CLI documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create#--config) and I combine it with the [container spec description](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/CustomJobSpec#ContainerSpec)

```
workerPoolSpecs:
  machineSpec:
    machineType: n1-highmem-2
  replicaCount: 1
  containerSpec:
    imageUri: gcr.io/ucaip-test/ucaip-training-test
    args:
    - port=8500
    env:
    - name: envName1,
      value: envValue1
    - name: envName2,
      value: envValue2
    command:
    - start
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not using the CLI. This is a configuration file to be passed with the `--config` option. As I have written in the original question, I'd prefer not to use a configuration file and only the command line interface. Or can I used the configuration file only for the environment variables? Or two configuration files?

Comment: Not sure to understand. If you don't want to use the CLI, you can use the API. But you have to provide the YAML config to set the machine, container and env defintiion

Comment: I want to use the CLI. It is the point. I don't want a configuration file. You provided a configuration file in your answer :) Everything that there is in the configuration file you provided can also be passed directly to the CLI. Everything except the env field, or I don't know how.

Comment: This feature may not have been implemented. If you run `gcloud ai custom-jobs create --help`, you can get a full list of what is passable. Someone asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302528/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-gcloud-beta-ai-custom-jobs-create-with-cust. Have you tried this with `gcloud beta`? Also, have you tried the `--args` field? It seems that it can pass args into your container.

Comment: Also, on a side note... `--config` is part of the CLI, so using a config file = using the CLI as intended. As a workaround, you could create the YAML file in bash and pass it all as one command.